# What is the context of methods called by before_save in a Rails 3 model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I honestly had no idea what to call this any other way (or what to actually look for).

So, In my ActiveRecord (...app/model/s/account.rb/) I have the following:

```
validates :username, :password, :email, :presence => true
validates :username, :email, :uniqueness => true
validates :username, :length => { :within => 5..30}
validates :password, :length => { :within => 6..128}
validates :password, :confirmation => true
validates :email, :format => { :with => /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i }
before_save :encrypt_password

private

    def encrypt_password
        require "digest"
        @account.password = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(@account.password)
    end
```

And I get the error:

> undefined method `password' for nil:NilClass

Why does it report `@account` as nil? Well, might be because @account doesn't exist outside the View/Controller, but I (honest to god) couldn't think of any other way of doing this.

P.S: I tried putting the `encrypt_password` inside the controller; it still didn't work (different error, though).

Comment: have you tried using just ":password" ?

Comment: Yep. And that one failed, too.(syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end)

Comment: try creating account variable from "form" where you submit data. ie:- @account = Account.new(params[:userform])

Comment: @Stephen - That one didn't work! :( @Harry - I already have, but that one's in the controller though. And everything works fine, I can even store it unto the database, the only thing that's not working out is storing the password in an encrypted form.

Comment: Try self.password ... see: http://www.reubenthiessen.com/archives/using-before_save-in-the-model/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the method to read:

```
def encrypt_password
  require 'digest'
  self.password = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(self.password)
end
```

The instance variable @account, which you use in the controller and view, refers to an instance of the class Account, which is what you're working on in this file. So, presumably, you're doing something like this in the controller:

```
@account = Account.new(params)
@account.save!
```

The instance of class Account receives the 'save!' call and fires its before_save callback, where it needs to refer to itself as 'self', not @account (which is the name your controller has for it).

**Side note:** you should require 'digest' at the top of your class file rather than inside the method - there's no need to load the digest library every time you want to hash a password.

Comment: N.B. you don't have to prefix password with 'self' in the method, I just think it's clearer to explain that way.

Comment: Ah, I could kiss you! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
 def self.hash_password(password = '')
      self.password = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(password)
 end
```